# Get the Extension details from list of Extensions that got the call in RingCentral

Tags: calllog, ringcentral

I have a question in RingCentral: if we have multiple Extensions or Users in our account, then how to get the details of the Extension or User which got the call.

A call can be received by a particular User or Extension, but how to check which User/Extension have done that? Any API which can reflect that?
Please help, I didn't found any reference or documentation link that can answer that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the extension details, you need to look the Account **Call-Logs** with following API:

```
/v1.0/account/{accountId}/call-log
```

with ***'view' = 'Detailed'***, like this:

```
/v1.0/account/{accountId}/call-log?view=Detailed
```

Your requirement is already answered here:
https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/318/how-do-we-identify-which-extension-picked-up-the-c.html

As per the above link, the Account level **Call-Logs** would return the legs with the Detailed view that contains the **"to"** information about the extension which picked up the Call.